# Asking about jquery-ui and jquery-min (2)

Tags: jquery

Thank you for your previous replies, the code I have pasted below includes your last changes, it still does't work, all I can see is the jquery-min , I can see anything from jquery-ui.

I am using Jquery-min CDN file from google hosting in a simple HTML, hosted by Apache 2.4 , and script javascript jquery files. The jquery-min script file works fine, but I can't understand why the jquery-ui script does not function well, for example the jquery-ui calender functions, but the jquery-ui buttons with icons inside do not work. How can I fix this this ? Is there a problem with the script I am using, or am I not writing the code very well ? The code I am using is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Jquery Test</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#driver").click(function(event) {
                    $('#stage').load('result.html');
                });
            });



            $('#button').button({
                label: 'Test',
                icons: {
                    primary: 'ui-icon-circle-plus',
                    secondary: null
                }
            });



            $("button[type=submit]").button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus"
                }
            }).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="button">Button Tag </button>
        <input type="submit" value="Input Tag(submit)" />
        <div id="stage" style="background-color:cc0;">
            STAGE
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="driver" value="load Data" />

        <button type="submit">
            Add Driver
        </button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to put the calls to `.button()` inside `$(document).ready()`. Your code is trying to add buttons to elements that don't exist yet.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I saw the buttons are formatted now.

Comment: This is basic jQuery technique, it should be explained in any tutorial. I guess it's time for you to do some actual research instead of just cutting and pasting code.